# Massive Dirac model Chern number 1/2

Tags: chern-simons-theory, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Why is massive Dirac model have a Chern number as half? I know this is something related to anomalies. And for fermions we have half, for bosons we have integer. But I failed to find any good explanation for this, everyone just treat this as common sense I guess. Does this has anything to do with the spinor space? Thanks!

Comment: "And for fermions we have half, for bosons we have integer" where does this come from? I think this is plainly nonsense. Massive Dirac fermions having 1/2 Chern number is a fact which you can check by direct calculation. For any actual band structure of fermions in 2D the Chern number must be an integer. So the resolution is that massive Dirac fermion is a low-energy field theory which neglects high-energy stuff, and the contribution from the stuff "outside" the theory will make it an integer.

Comment: Another possibility is that the massive Dirac fermion actually exists on the surface of a 3D topological insulator. I'm sure someone will elaborate on this...

Comment: @MengCheng thanks for your answer, I checked by direct calculation that it is 1/2, the question is why I get a half instead of 1. I really don't know how the stuff outside the theory will make it 1...to say this is unphysical is not the proper answer from my view.

Comment: It's not unphysical. For any continuum field theory one has to worry about regularization: how your theory is cut off at short distance? This is very physical. To be more concrete, consider adding a quadratic term $\sim k^2$ to the diagonal part. The addition will regulate the Dirac fermion for large $k$, but reproduces the same small $k$ behavior. The Chern number will immediately become $1$. To see another example, you can consider a lattice realization in the so-called Haldane's honeycomb lattice model.

Comment: One can approximate the band structure by *two* massive Dirac cones. The mass of one of the cones can be tuned to be much larger than the other, essentially pushing the cone into the "high-energy" band. Then it seems that at low energy we just have one massive Dirac fermion. The Chern number is still an integer, because secretly there are two Dirac cones. Once I have more time I can put in more details to the claims made in these comments...

Comment: @MengCheng thanks for your explanation, this is very helpful. But extending one simple model to a more complicated model where everything works is not what I want... What I really want to know is why this simple model can violates integer Chern number law, which should not depend on the model one choose.

Comment: You need to know the context of the integer Chern number law, which says that for an actual band (i.e. arising from a lattice) the Chern number is an integer. So the implication is that an actual band is never truly a single massive Dirac fermion; there is a second one somewhere. I'm not trying to make it more complicated, just trying to show you what is hidden in the regularization, without which quantum field theories do not make sense.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks for your answer, still I don't understand why regularization is necessary. I will do some search.

Comment: @MengCheng I know the reason now, the thing is when I do the integral, there is no BZ, so I integrate over a 2d infinite sheet, and this is not a manifold. So we don't have integer winding number as in the case of two manifold mapping, and the mapping could be arbitrary.